# Objective-C, how to pass char[] to method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, class

I have this method that makes a call to another method. How to I pass the char[] to it instead of having the char[] inside it?

```
- (IBAction)goThere(id)sender {

   // char hex[] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0x15}; <-- this is what I want to pass to elseWhere
   // NSString *text = "some string";  <-- it would be cool to send other things too.

    [self elseWhere];
}

- (void)elseWhere {

char hex[] = {0xDA, 0xFF, 0x15};

...

}
```

Ideally I would be able to send char[] from goThere, being able to re-use the char[] as needed, unfortunately i'm not advanced in this. thanks

Comment: You should pick up an Intro to Objective-C book and read it a few times.  This is pretty basic stuff and you aren't going to get very far with piece-meal questions like this.   (Please don't take that as an insult -- we were all there once and learning any new system is often daunting, but stepping back and looking at it, well, systemically is often critical!).

Comment: @bbum, no worries at all — i agree with you. I was just going around in circles with it so thought i would ask to get an idea of where to start. Are there any books in particular that really stick out to you as good starting points with objective-c/cocoa? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(IBAction)goThere:(id)sender {
    char hex[] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0x15};
    [self elseWhereWithData:hex length:3];
}

-(void)elseWhereWithData:(char*)array length:(int)length {
    // array is a char array with a length of length.
    // Do stuff....strong text
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the tip. if I need to send other things to elseWhere also how does that work? like for example NSString *text = ...

Comment: Just change the signature of elseWhere to `-(void)elseWhereWithData:(char*)array length:(int)length andString:(NSString*)string {/* ... */}`

Comment: i see, so if you want to send more than one type to the same method it wouldn't work, right? such as char[] and NSString.

Comment: Yes it will. Just change the parameters around to whatever you want.

Comment: that worked, i had to change (char*) to (const void *), but you gave me a little better idea where to start. ty!

Comment: @JoeHabadas: What do you mean by “I had to change (char*) to (const void *)”? It's valid to pass a `char` array to an argument that takes a pointer to `char`. Did you get an error message? If so, what was it?

Comment: I'm using (char []) in the statement now. it's strange because even if i set some of them to int, void *, etc. they end up switching back to something else. sometimes when i try and change them i get and error that says it's read only. i'm still trying to wrap my head around it all.

Comment: @JoeHabadas: In the statement? You shouldn't need to cast the array; it's already a valid value for an argument of that type. Type in declarations don't “switch back to something else” on their own; aside from the limited set of automatic conversions of values (e.g., `int` promotion), the type is whatever you said it is. What do you mean by “says it's read only”? What's the exact error message?

Comment: @peter-hosey, I figured out that problem; the variable is in a block — which I had zero knowledge about. I've corrected the code to include __block and all seems fine so far. thanks again for your help!

Comment: @JoeHabadas: Note that `__block` exists to enable the block to return values to its caller outside of the `return` statement (which may not be available because, e.g., you're dispatching the block with GCD). If you dispatch the block synchronously or call it directly, and the block (or anything that the block calls) changes the contents of the `__block` variable, the caller will receive those changes. Make sure you mean to do (or even allow) that, or have the block create its own copy of the array in its own variable.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
-(void)method:(char[])array {
    //do something with array
}
```

?